# How to traverse through dictionary keys after checking the flag and append

Tags: python, dictionary

My list of dictionary is below

```
d = 
[ { 'type': 'AB', 'name': 'a@gmail.com', 'flag':'Y' },
 { 'type': 'AB', 'name': 'cd@gmail.com', 'flag''Y' }, 
{ 'type': 'DE', 'name': 'm@gmail.com | n@gmail.com', 'flag':'Y' }, 
{ 'type': 'FG', 'name': '0@gmail.com', 'flag':'N' }, 
{ 'type': 'FG', 'name': 'p@gmail.com', 'flag':'N' } ,
 { 'type': 'DE', 'name': '0@gmail.com', 'flag':'Y' }]
```

- After checking the `flag` and `type` is same then append to the the `type`
- The name `|` has to seperated by comma

Expected out

```
[ { 'type': 'AB', 'name':[ 'a@gmail.com', 'cd@gmail.com'], 'flag':'Y' },
 { 'type': 'DE', 'name': ['m@gmail.com , n@gmail.com', '0@gmail.com'], 'flag':'Y' }, 
{ 'type': 'FG', 'name': '0@gmail.com',  'p@gmail.com'], 'flag':'N' } ]
```

Comment: You variable d is a list !!

Comment: @Wonka changed thanks for notifying

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @Wonka i have edited there was one type was there

Comment: You said that you wanted it split at `|` but in your expected out you have `'m@gmail.com , n@gmail.com'` instead of them being 2 seperate items

Comment: You should edit in the missing `[` in the last line of the results and also the missing `:` in the second item of `d` (currently it's `'flag''Y'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want it to:

```
new_list = []
for old_dict in d:
    old_dict["name"] = list(map(str.strip, old_dict["name"].split("|")))
    for new_dict in new_list:
        if (
            old_dict["type"] == new_dict["type"]
            and old_dict["flag"] == new_dict["flag"]
        ):
            new_dict["name"] += old_dict["name"]
            break
    else:
        new_list.append(old_dict)
```

So, making a new list of dictionaries from the old one while combining the `name` attributes. Let me know if it works or if you have any questions.